# Reshape in JOGL, OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm having an issue, where on a `resize` event, the graphics in the canvas is not displayed correctly until `repaint()` is called in the the `reshape()` function. Isn't `reshape()` called during a `resize`? Why do I need to call `repaint()` again? Also, when resizing, the graphics seems to initially pick a random area in the screen, and then position themselves correctly. It does not happen in a single step.

Also, when drawing graphics, is it okay to populate them in the `init()` function as below or should they be in `display()`?

```
@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClearColor(.0f, .0f, .2f, 0.9f);
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluLookAt(45, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glCallList(2);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    gl.glFlush();
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LESS);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_NORMALIZE);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL2.GL_CCW);
    gl.glCullFace(GL2.GL_BACK);
    gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);

    int buf[] = new int[1];
    int sbuf[] = new int[1];

    gl.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, buf, 0);
    gl.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_SAMPLES, sbuf, 0);

    int ind = 0;
    int nind = 0; // normal index

    gl.glNewList(1, GL2.GL_COMPILE);
    gl.glColorMaterial(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    gl.glRotatef(45, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glTranslatef(-tr_x, -tr_y, -tr_z);
    while (ind < fvert.size()) {
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glColor4f(.94f, .43f, 0.12f, 0.5f); // upper border
        gl.glNormal3f(fnorm.get(nind + 4).x, fnorm.get(nind + 4).y, fnorm.get(nind + 4).z);
        gl.glVertex3f(fvert.get(ind + 8).x, fvert.get(ind + 8).y, fvert.get(ind + 8).z);
        gl.glVertex3f(fvert.get(ind + 9).x, fvert.get(ind + 9).y, fvert.get(ind + 9).z);
        gl.glVertex3f(fvert.get(ind + 10).x, fvert.get(ind + 10).y, fvert.get(ind + 10).z);

        gl.glEnd();

        ind = ind + 16;
        nind = nind + 8;
    }
    gl.glEndList();

            //buffer two init here.

}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(45, w / (float) h, 0.1f, 1000.0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);

    canvas.repaint();   //?????
}

  //*****Updated************
    @Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    double fov = (Math.PI / 4.0);
    double zmm = Math.abs(mminz - mmaxz);
    double camdist = (zmm / 2.0) / Math.tan(fov / 2.0);

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(camdist, w / (float) h, 0.1f, 1000.0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);

    display(drawable); 

    //canvas.repaint(); // ?????
}
```

Comment: Are you using an animator?

Comment: No. I`m not using Animator.

Comment: I can't help you with the code, but I can explain you the theory. When you resize, `reshape()` will be called and here you update the projection matrix and the viewport, and you are already doing this, so it looks fine. But after that, you need a `display()` that render again on the new resized area, because since the size has been modified, you need to render again with the new projection and viewport. `init` seems fine, but you are using deprecated OpenGL, which is highly discouraged.

Comment: You mean GL2? What should I be using?

Comment: I mean you should use modern OpenGL calls, like [these ones](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle)

Comment: I added display(), and it doesn`t seem to help with the resizing. See update above. repaint() works.

Comment: Try only `canvas.repaint()`

Comment: elect is right, just use an animator. You can use my example (using deprecated OpenGL methods): https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98 If you call frame.setResizable(true), it will go on working. What you do isn't very clean and may cause some troubles. Next time, please provide a SSCCE instead of a piece of code: http://sscce.org